# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE flag is deprecated in Android R

Tags: android, android-11

SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE flag is deprecated in Android R.
Google's recommendation is to use getInsetsIgnoringVisibility().
How to use getInsetsIgnoringVisibility() API. How to achieve SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE behaviour with new API on decor view